# Где можно узнать "координаты" цвета?

Tags: python

```python
COLOR = (250, 250, 250)
```

Мне надо покрасить прямоугольник в зелёный цвет.  Есть какой-нибудь источник с информацией по всем цветам в *Python*?  То есть,где я могу взять "координаты" конкретного цвета?

Comment: https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.html

Comment: лучше https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB

Comment: На будущее, не стоит вставлять в сообщения код скриншотом.  Пишите код текстом, чтобы отвечающие могли быстрее вам помочь.

Answer (score 1):

https://allcalc.ru/node/402

Тут можно просматривать цвет в онлайн режиме.

На всякий случай пишу, что означает каждая цифра в скобках (R,G,B)==(250,250,250)